# Breeze 1.4.2 Nuget External packages cannot depend on packages that target projects

Tags: nuget, breeze, q

When installing Breeze.WebApi 1.4.2 in a fresh project I am getting this error:

```
PM> Install-Package Breeze.WebApi
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Breeze.Client (≥ 1.4.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Q'.
Install-Package : **External packages cannot depend on packages that target projects.**
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Breeze.WebApi
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

What is going on here?

TJ

Comment: Are you installing the sample application for Web API or what?

Comment: No i am creating a new Asp.Net Empty Web Application project and then adding the Breeze client and server package. This has been working before. Must be something after they updated breeze.

Comment: Same problem for upgrading to new Breeze version here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading NuGet Package Manager worked for me.

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget